# Hashtagging and Mentions in a Blog Post/Comment

Tags: 2013, blog, community

I have a SharePoint Blog site configured and used in my company. I want to increase engagement on that blog by using social features like Hashtagging and mentions. Is there any way that I could do this?

The end result that I am looking for is to make the blog, and specially the comments, similar in functionality to a MicroFeed. So, as the end-user is entering a blog post or a comment, he can use Hash-Tagging and Mentions in that entry and also these reflect as activities on the Newsfeed (Both, for the end-user as well as his/her followers).

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this for? 2013, 2010?

Comment: This is for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 includes microblogging functionality similar to Twitter. Using the microblogging capabilities of SharePoint 2013, you can tag other users using the @ symbol and tag topics using the hashtag # symbol.

You can tag a person by including @ (ie: @johnsmith)
or 
You can tag a topic, page, or keyword by using # (ie: #contoso)

Items you are following will show up on your "Tags & Notes"

Comment: This would be a separate Newsfeed within the Blog Site. I am looking to add the tagging features within the Blog Post and Comments directly.
Ex: A Blog used by sales folk talking about customer stories. They may want to "Mention" the sales guys responsible and Hash-Tag keywords like Customer names or Parts. The Hash-Tagging functionality can be achieved through the Enterprise metadata column so I am mainly looking for Mentions.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sharepoint 2013 offers Microblogging. You can add mentions and tags within your blog post. Check out this site for examples and screenshots. http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/SharePoint-is-FINALLY-Social-mdash-Microblogging-and-Newsfeeds-in-SharePoint-2013#.Up9rl9JDtmA

Comment: I went through the URL and I could find no mention at all for blogs ("Macro" Blogs for want of a better term). There are some stories, like the customer stories example in my last comment, where the text is too big to make sense in a microblog. It is best kept in its own "Blog" with one blog post per story. In that story, there will be individuals mentioned and it would be really nice to have that as an @Mention.

Comment: He clearly did not understand the question.